# knockout.js options binding not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the following code.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.menusarray">
    <span data-bind="text: Name">Course Option Name: </span>
    <select data-bind="options:CourseOptions, 
                       optionsText: 'Name', 
                       optionsValue:'Id',
                       value: $root.selectedoptionsid"></select>
</div>
```

`$root.menusarray` contains an array of objects and `CourseOptions` is another array of objects within. `$root.selectedoptionsid` is an observable array of ids which is not a part of `CourseOptions` or `$root.menusarray`.

I am trying to display the `'Name'` whose `'Id'` matches with `$root.selectedoptionsid`'s current value or the first `'Name'` in the `CourseOptions` array.

If no match is found, a new selection must also be stored at the same location in the `$root.selectedoptionsid` observable array. The length of `$root.selectedoptionsid` is equal to `CourseOptions`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just trying to understand... why is $root.selectedoptionsid an array?  Shouldn't it be just an observable, which stores the value of current selected CourseOptions value.

Comment: $root.selectedoptionsid is an observable array. no it cannot be a simple observable because as u can see the <select> element is within a foreach loop whose number of iterations cannot be same each time. so if it is an observable how can i determine from which drop-down list it was set and also it cannot contain selection from each list.